# pandas: stop pandas from auto displaying 0.40 as 0.4

Tags: pandas, dataframe, formatting, display

How do I stop pandas from automatically converting 0.40 to 0.4 in dataframe values?

I believe the solution was has something to do with 'display' options and formatting? but I can't find any info.

something like:

```
display.float_format(#.##)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a format string object as the arg to [`set_option`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html) for `display.float_format`:

```
In [167]:
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{0:.2f}'.format)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3))
df

Out[167]:
      0     1     2
0  0.84 -0.91 -1.44
1  1.82  0.38 -0.47
2 -0.07  2.09  1.81
3  0.09 -2.05 -0.92
4  0.26 -1.94 -1.09
```

The underlying data is unaffected:

```
In [168]:
df.iloc[0][0]

Out[168]:
0.84179409715165521
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Printing the df shows the values correctly but when I write the df to excel, it still comes up as 0.4? any idea?

Comment: Is this just a display formatting problem though? for instance when you move to a specific cell what value does it display? I'm not sure that this should affect how the data gets exported, I'm not familiar with the python excel modules which is what pandas. Saying that `to_excel` also supports `float_format` arg: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html so you could try that

Comment: Tried that, had no effect, not that important right now so thumbs up, thanks again Ed!

Answer (score 0):

use list comprehensions to change all values in a particular series.  Change the `.2` to whatever level of precision you want.

```
a = ["{0:.2f}".format(val) for val in df.column_name]
df.loc[:,'column_name'] = a
```